# How to write unit test case to mock redis cluster using jest

Tags: typescript, redis, jestjs, ioredis

Can you please help me to mock the redis cluster?

```
const Redis: any = require('ioredis');
const Promise: any = require('bluebird');

// Promise original enable for cancelation
Promise.config({ cancellation: true });

// Change to use bluebird Promises.
Redis.Promise = Promise;

const cluster: any = new Redis.Cluster([
  {
    port: '123',
    host: 'https://host'
  }
]);

async updateCache(Id, obj): Promise<any> {
  let consolidatedIndexObj = instanceToPlain(obj);

  return cluster
    .hset('TESTINDEX', ID, JSON.stringify(consolidatedIndexObj))
    .timeout(2000)
    .then((cache: any) => {

      return cache;
    })
    .catch((error: any) =>
    //
    );
};
```

I tried to mock the redis cluster using this package.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis-mock

Answer (score 0):

[Testcontainers](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-node) is a NodeJS library that supports tests, providing lightweight, throwaway instances of anything that can run in a Docker container. Test container work with Docker desktop, Rancher and with some tweaks Podman as well.

I recommend you start with a simple Redis image to play around, and only after you think you have figured out how to weave test containers into your test suite look at building a custom multi-container docker image representing a Redis Cluster. Building a docker image representation for Redis cluster for unit testing is super easy and you don't need any fancy scripts to handle failover, volume mounts etc.